# How do I count the number of sequential recurrences?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file which I have performed an operation on. I now have a column that is populated by either the value 1 or 0.

What do I need to do to count the number of "1's" that appear in a consecutive sequence.

My array looks like this:
1
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
0
1
1
0

What I need to be able to extract is that we saw a run of 5 1's then a run of 2 1's. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. For the sake of improving the quality of your question, please share with us what you've already tried. It may be useful for you to read [how to ask](http://superuser.com/help/asking). Tags are not needed in the title question nor are salutations needed in the body of the text.

Answer (score 1):

This is not elegant, but it will work:

After your column of '1's and '0's,

make your 2nd column:

```
0
=(A2+B1)*A2  <-- You can just drag-fill this downward
=(A3+B2)*A3
=(A4+B3)*A4
.
.
.
```

...and make the 3rd column:

```
0
=SUMIF(B3,0,B2)  <-- You can just drag-fill this downward as well
=SUMIF(B4,0,B3)
=SUMIF(B5,0,B4)
.
.
.
```

The 3rd column will show the number of '1's in each group, with the sum beside the last '1' in the run.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [COUNTIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) function you can tell excel to count the occurrences of a specific criteria in a given range.

```
COUNTIF(range,criteria)
```

Lets say your data is in column A and rows 1 through 13, you would use the following to count the number of times "1" occurs.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A13, 1)
```

Adjust the range to the range you want to count and the criteria to what you want to count.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm not sure this is exactly what the OP is looking for. The way I understand it, given an arbitrary range of cells, determine the length of a consecutive series of values - 1 in this case. I imagine he's going to need VBA for this - I could do it in Python, but I'm not sure Excel (without VBA) has the necessary ability for temporary variables like counters...

Comment: MattDMo - you have that correct. I don't need to know how many 1's there are in total, just how many sit in each consecutive block. I seem to recall a former colleague doing this for me years back. It would be inexact, but I suppose I could test blocks of 5, 6, 7, 8 etc...

Comment: My mistake. I misunderstood what was being asked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  My approach was ugly and inefficient, but it worked.

I made a second column which looked to see if the adjacent cell value was what I was looking for, and if so, give a number of 0+the value of the cell above it in the second column.

I made a third column where each cell looked at the adjacent cell in column 2, and if the value was greater than the one below it, to give a value of 0+ the max value in the third column up to the row of the cell.  If not, it spit out an empty value ("")  In this way I was able to put an sequential identifier number.

I made a fourth column where which looked at the adjacent cell in column 3, and if it was any value except blank, to put the value of that row from column 2.

I then made a fifth column which began with 1, and every row was one higher than the previous row, up to the max value from Column 3.

I finished by making a sixth column which used the lookup function.  The lookup value would be the adjacent cell in column 5.  The Range would be column 3 and 4.  I would have it spit out the value from column 4.

I define a sequence of identical values as a run.  Each number on column 5 represents a run.  Each number in column 6 represents the the size of that run.  This allows you to generate the sizes of each of the runs.

Like I said, this is an ugly way to go about this, and could probably be written a lot cleaner in VBA, but it is effective.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think of it as counting consecutive numbers. Think of it as finding the position of the first 0.

=match(0,A1:A14,0)-1

Drag down the formula, letting the range adjust as you drag down. It will give you the number of 1's you have in a row at any given point in the data.